# Trying to understand logical operator (a && a === b && a === C) Used in React JS sample

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logical-operators

Can someone kindly, explain what the above return with example.
And what happen when you change it to ( a === b ===C).
Have been trying to understand that logic better in reactjs.org, although working well but how the logic works still not clear in my mind

Sample code copied from React tutorial

`

```
function calculateWinner(squares) {
    const lines = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6],
    ];
    //alert(lines.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
        //alert(squares[a]);
        if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
            return squares[a];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

`

From ReactJS.org
 https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: Which part of it are you having trouble with?

Comment: _“And what happen when you change it to ( a === b ===C)”_ - then it will just be nonsense that means something completely different, and won’t achieve the same thing any more. This is really not very react-specific - basically you are trying to outsource learning some JS-basics here, so -1 for that.

Comment: if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
            return squares[a];
        } how is it executing?

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript's `if` statement (and other flow-control structures) *coerce* values if they're not already booleans. The line

```
if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
```

is joining together three expressions with `&&`, which does a logical AND on them. The three expressions are:

- `squares[a]`
- `squares[a] === squares[b]`
- `squares[a] === squares[c]`

`&&` takes only two operands (the ones on either side), let's call them `x` and `y` (`x && y`). It evaluates `x` and, if that result is falsy,¹ takes that result as the `&&` result; otherwise, it evaluates `y` and takes that as the `&&` result:

```js
let x = 0;
let y = 2;
console.log(x && y); // 0 - `x` was falsy, so that value was the result
x = 1;
console.log(x && y); // 2 - `x` was truthy, so `y` was evaluated and that value was the result
```

So `squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b]` will be truthy if both of its operands evaluate to a truthy value, or falsy if *either* of them evaluates to a falsy value.

Then the result of that (let's call it `r`) is used in `r && squares[a] === squares[c]`, which also is truthy if both operands have a truthy value and falsy if either of them is falsy.

Once all that is done, `if` coerces the truthy/falsy result to boolean (truthy => true, falsy => false) and branches into the body of the `if` if the condition is `true`.

> And what happen when you change it to `( a === b ===C)`

It would stop working, because `a === b === C` doesn't do what you think it does. It does `a === b`, which results in `true` or `false` (call it `r`), and then does `r === C`. Unless `C` is a boolean, that will be false.

---

¹ *falsy* - A value is *falsy* if it converts to `false` when converted to boolean. The falsy values are `0`, `NaN`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false` (bizarrely, on browsers `document.all` is also falsy for historical reasons — details in Chapter 17 of my book, *JavaScript: The New Toys* if you're interested). All other values are *truthy*.

Answer (score 0):

```
squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]
```

In above statement, square[a] should be equal to square[b] and square[c] and also should be truthy value.

**Truthy Values :** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

if you change it `square[a] === square[b] === square[c]`, then it will first compare first two and result boolean value will be compared to `square[c]`

for example, if

```
square[a] = 1;
square[b] = 1;
square[c] = 1;
```

then first `square[a] === square[b]` will be evaluated which will return `true`. Then `true === square[c]` will be evaluated, which will return `false.

Answer (score 0):

`foo === bar === baz` doesn't mean "if foo, bar, and baz are identical."

It evaluates the first part of the expression first, so think of it this way:

```
(foo === bar) === baz
```

What does `foo === bar` evaluate to? Either `true` or `false`. So it becomes either `true === baz` or `false === baz`.

`foo === bar && foo === baz`, on the other hand, *would* mean "if foo, bar, and baz are identical."

Answer (score 0):

In case if you don't have an understanding of logic gates(i.e. &&, ||) first read about them or if you know and this logic that you mention above

`if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c])`

doesn't seem you easy then understand this logic then try to understand below logic it works the same as above

`if (squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[b] === squares[c])`

Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found it that `(squares[a] && (squares[a] === squares[b]) && (squares[a] === squares[c]))`
this would be a good way of representing the answer that i understood.. i was anding before the equals...
So when `squares[a] is not null and squares[a]===squares[b] and squares[a]===squares[c]` then the outcome is `true` and the return value is executed ..

Its a bit confusing notation ..thanks to everyone for helping

Comment: What? Is this an answer to the two-year old question (that was already answered, and more legibly)?

Answer (score 0):

```
var a=null, b=null ,c=null;

if(a === b && a === c)   // it gives true
    console.log("true 1 case")

if(a && a === b && a === c)
    console.log("true 2 case")

If you are using 1st condition then it gives true in all null values
so they use (a && a) because to get actual value ('X' or 'O').
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first time with javascript/react, then you might have a hard time understanding the tic tac toe example like I and the author of this question was.
I come from C++ and java, so naturally, the code didn't make sense at first.  After an hour of trying to figure this out, this is what I had to think about to make it make sense.

The if statement is doing:

```
(squares[a]) && (squares[a] == squares[b]) && (squares[a] == squares[c])
```

The first expression `squares[a]` is equivalent to `squares[a] != null`

The other 2 are just comparing each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
   const [a, b, c, d] = lines[i];
 if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c] && squares[a] === squares[d]) {
   return squares[a];
   }
 }
```

The above code worked for me with a 4x4 grid for the React tutorial. Basically, I added squares[a] === squares[d]. Hope this helps somebody who is trying this tutorial out with a 4x4 grid.

Answer (score 0):

first check if squares[a] is X or O. Let it is X, then check if squares[b] is X. Then check if squares[c] is X.

```
if (squares[a] && 
    (squares[a] === squares[b]) && 
    (squares[a] === squares[c])) { 
    return squares[a];
}
```